# Unable to view RadChart data when RadScheduleView placed in the same view

Tags: wpf, telerik, radchart, radscheduleview

I have a screen in which i am required to place both RadChart and RadScheduleView . RadChart has some data associated with it, and RadScheduleView has no data. When I add the reference for RadScheduleView , which is "Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView", the data which is associated with the charts are no longer visible and in place of that data, random data like " Chart axis label, ChartChartTitle" etc appears. Why is this happening, and how can this be solved?

Please refer the following link for sample code regarding the mentioned error
http://www.filedropper.com/radchartbug